# Why is set not calculating my unique integers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I just started teaching myself Python last night via Python documentation, tutorials and SO questions.

So far I can ask a user for a file, open and read the file, remove all # and beginning \n in the file, read each line into an array, and count the number of integers per line.

I want to calculate the number of unique integers per line. I realized that Python uses a set capability which I thought would work perfectly for this calculation. However, I always receive the value of one greater than the prior value (I will show you). I looked at other SO posts related to sets and do not see what I am not missing and have been stumped for a while.

Here is the code:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#"):
            #calculate the number of integers per line
            names_list.append(line)
            #print "There are ", len(line.split()), " numbers on this line"

            #print names_list

           #calculate the number of unique integers
            myset = set(names_list)
            print myset
            myset_count = len(myset)
            print "unique:",myset_count
```

For further explanation:

names_list is:

```
['1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 5\n', '14 62 48 14\n', '1 3 5 7 9\n', '123 456 789 1234 5678\n', '34 34 34 34 34\n', '1\n', '1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 7 7 7 1 1\n']
```

and my_set is:

```
set(['1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 5\n', '1 3 5 7 9\n', '34 34 34 34 34\n', '14 62 48 14\n', '1\n', '1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 7 7 7 1 1\n', '123 456 789 1234 5678\n'])
```

The output I receive is:

```
unique: 1
unique: 2
unique: 3
unique: 4
unique: 5
unique: 6
unique: 7
```

The output that should occur is:

```
unique: 6
unique: 3
unique: 5
unique: 5
unique: 1
unique: 1
unique: 7
```

Any suggestions as to why my set per line is not calculating the correct number of unique integers per line? I would also like any suggestions on how to improve my code in general (if you would like) because I just started learning Python by myself last night and would love tips. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that as you are iterating over your file you are appending each line to the list `names_list`. After that, you build a set out of these lines. Your text file does not seem to have any duplicate lines, so printing the length of your set just displays the current number of lines you have processed.

Here's a commented fix:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#"):
            numbers = line.split() # splits the string by whitespace and gives you a list
            unique_numbers = set(numbers) # builds a set of the strings in numbers
            print(len(unique_numbers)) # prints number of items in the set
```

Note that we are using the currently processed line and build a set from it (after splitting the line). Your original code stores all lines and then builds a set from the lines in each loop.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation. I made changes and everything works great. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
myset = set(names_list)
```

should be

```
myset = set(line.split())
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.